# Go: How to use middleware pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, go

I have a function that executes only with specific conditions (e.g. *role == 'Administrator'*). Now, I use *'if'* statement. But it could be situations when number of conditions is high and *'if'* with long definition looks not so esthetic.
Is it available mechanism in Go (or related with Go framework) allows implementation of middleware **concept** (action filters)?
*For example, ASP.NET MVC allows to do this:*

```
[MyFilter]
public ViewResult Index()
{
     // Filter will be applied to this specific action method
}
```

*So, MyFilter() implemented in the separate class allows better code composition and testing.*

**Update:**
Revel (web framework for the Go) provides similar functionality with
Interceptors (function that is invoked by the framework BEFORE or AFTER an action invocation): https://revel.github.io/manual/interceptors.html

Comment: What is the goal of an action filter?  And either way, I'd air on the side of no, Go favors simplicity and this strikes me as something that leads to more complexity.

Comment: Action Filters are custom attributes that provide declarative means to add pre-action and post-action behavior to the controller's methods. Very good explanation (from point of ASP.NET MVC) is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577776/Filters-and-Attributes-in-ASPNET-MVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of thing is typically done with *middleware* in Go. The easiest is to show by example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/foo", middleware(handler))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
}

func middleware(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.URL.Path = "/MODIFIED"

        // Run the next handler
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

As you can see, a middleware is a function that:

1. accepts a `http.HandlerFunc` as an argument;
2. returns a `http.HandlerFunc`;
3. calls the `http.handlerFunc` passed in.

With this basic technique you can "chain" as many middlewares as you like:

```
http.HandleFunc("/foo", another(middleware(handler)))
```

---

There are some variants to this pattern, and most Go frameworks use a slightly different syntax, but the concept is typically the same.

Answer (score -1):

Revel (web framework for the Go) provides similar functionality with
**Interceptors** (function that is invoked by the framework BEFORE or AFTER an action invocation).
Concept and implementation described here: https://revel.github.io/manual/interceptors.html