# Using intermediate handler function to route requests

Tags: go

I was thinking of ways to do routing with the standard library. Is it valid to have a handler function that will call other handler functions depending on the request type? e.g.

```
func main() {
    m := http.NewServeMux()
    m.HandleFunc("/books", books)
    // ...
}

func books(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
        case "GET":
            getBooks(w, r)
        case "POST":
            createBook(w, r)
    }
}
```

Is this good practice? I didn't want to declare a custom handler since I find functions to be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly valid; handlers are just functions so there is no reason it shouldn't be. In fact, this is how [middleware is usually implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40649419/660921).

There is nothing "magic" about handler functions at all. As long as you're writing to the correct file descriptor (`w http.ResponseWriter`) anything goes.

That doesn't mean that using this pattern is necessarily a good idea for all applications – routing libraries exist for a reason – but for smaller programs it will work just fine.

Comment: That's true, I've known that is how middleware is implemented but felt this was a bit different since it didn't involve higher order functions. The actual program flow is the same which is the most substantial aspect. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

> It's completely valid to have a `HandlerFunc` call another `HandlerFunc`.

In fact that's how you would implement **middleware** using the standard lib.

Here's a [**Post**](https://medium.com/@matryer/the-http-handler-wrapper-technique-in-golang-updated-bc7fbcffa702) by *Mat Ryer* (amazing guy btw) that explains in some further detail what he calls 
 **"http.Handler wrapper technique"**

The way you want to use `HandlerFunc`s reminds me of [Laravel's Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers), which I think are pretty neat. But using them carelessly could become an unnecessary overhead.

I would suggest you perhaps give [**julienschmidt/httprouter**](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) library a try.
It's pretty fast and easy to use.

Comment: I've used both httprouter (and gorilla mux AND fasthttp). I think there is some value in using the standard library especially on smaller projects. However the other points are useful, thanks for the resources.

Comment: I have not done the benchmarks, but using the standard router would probably make your app a tiny bit faster. But the difference should be negligible, but i found some of the libraries much easier to reason about and write. Code readability is pretty important, and I find standard lib a bit harder to read then some other solutions.

Comment: Actually the standard library is slower than most of those routers (according to what I've read). I've just been fascinated with the standard library and "idiomatic go" lately.

Comment: Hmm I'm surprised to hear that. It's not easy to find the golden middle ground between **idiomatic go** and **practical go**. Depends from case to case but sometimes idiomatic solution is not that practical. But I find frameworks like [beego](https://beego.me/) a serious overkill.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid, as mentioned in the other answers handlers are just functions.

The thing that changes is the request method; it might worth considering an implementation with a map. This could be more extensible as the number of handlers you need change.

```
type BookController struct {
    routes map[string]http.HandlerFunc
}

func (b BookController) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // beware this very basic example will panic if there's not a registered handler for r.Method
    // but I assume you'd have to do handling of missing method logic in your default switch anyway
    b.routes[r.Method].ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

And to register them:

```
m := http.NewServeMux()
b := BookController{}
b.routes = map[string]http.HandlerFunc{
    "GET": getBooks,
    "POST": createBooks,
}
m.Handle("/books", b)
```

Slightly more boiler plate, but might allow for easier adding / removing of handlers later.